# jquery bug shooting to top after point is reached and image copying

Tags: jquery, html, css

I added some simple jquery to a site that I am working on to make 2 elements slide into view once the user scrolls to a certain point on the screen. The animation does what I want it to but when I scroll down to the area, right before the animation finishes it instantly shoots me to the top of the page. When I scroll back down the animation is complete but it leaves what looks like a "copy" of the text that was moved in the area it moved from. How can I stop the page from shooting to the top and how can I stop the text from leaving a copy where it animates from?

here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1350) {
           $('#managecontent1').animate({left: '0px'},900);
           $('#managecontent2').animate({right: '0px'},900);
       }
            });
    });
```

here is what the text copying looks like

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: (a) If elements are moved around on the page while scrolling is in progress then it is maybe not surprising that native browser scroll gets confused. (b) You should at least detach the scroll handler once it has started the animations, to prevent it re-firing over and over. (c) Can't explain the apparent copy.

Comment: how would I detach the scroll handler?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.off()` to detach event handlers.

In the following code `.off()` is used :

- in conjunction with `setTimeout()` to temporarily detach the scroll handler before the animations have been triggered, in order to reduce the frequency at which the scroll handler fires
- to permanently detach the scroll handler once the animations have been triggered.

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
    function scrollHandler() {
        $(window).off('scroll.managecontent');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1350) {
            $('#managecontent1').animate({left: '0px'}, 900);
            $('#managecontent2').animate({right: '0px'}, 900);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(observeScroll, 200);//Adjust timeout to maximum acceptable value. 200 ms shouldn't be too far off the mark.
        }
    }
    function observeScroll() {
        $(window).on('scroll.managecontent', scrollHandler);
    }
    observeScroll();
});
```

This may or may not fix the issue.